# Making a timer in Ruby

Tags: ruby, timer

I want to make a timer in Ruby, where after a certain amount of time that the user chooses, the timer rings, or a message pops up. Also, would it be possible to make the timer ring until the user does a certain thing (such as a math problem)?

Comment: Here's 3 simple steps: 1) write down current time as start time; 2) every second (or so) compare current time with start time; 3) if specified number of seconds have passed since start time, ring the bell.

Comment: What kind of pop up message? Some text in the terminal? A pop up on a web browser? Or, on some GUI toolkit? What kind of ringing? A beep sound? Some functionality using a web browser? Playing an audio file from a web browser? Or from some music player?

Comment: You know, subset of the features you wan can be done in bash, using things like `cron`. In that case, save your bash script in a file and run each line in Ruby using `system( your_line )` command :-)))

Comment: This is a really vague question that needs better explanation.

Comment: I was thinking just some beeping (beeping that would keep going until you turned the timer off) or if thats not possible, a pop up kind of like the prompt feature in javascript, or like when you try to log out of a section on a mac. Also, I'm quite new at ruby (at coding in general) so I don't really know how to do the things Sergio said. If you could give me some code that'd be great. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Use threads:

```
user_input = Thread.new do
  print "Enter something: "
  Thread.current[:value] = gets.chomp
end

timer = Thread.new { sleep 3; user_input.kill; puts }

user_input.join
if user_input[:value]
  puts "User entered #{user_input[:value]}"
else
  puts "Timer expired"
end
```

Three threads are running in this code:

1. The `user_input` thread, which gets a string from the user and sets its `value` thread variable
2. The `timer` thread, which sleeps for three seconds and then kills the `user_input` thread
3. The main thread, which spawns the other two and then waits for the `user_input` thread to finish

Without the `timer` thread, the code would appear to work exactly like a single-threaded one that prompts for user input and then continues.  The execution of the two threads is serialized using #join.  The main thread gets the result of the user interaction by looking at the `user_input`'s `value` thread variable.

The addition of the `timer` thread causes the `user_input` thread to terminate early (3 seconds in this case).  When this happens, the `user_input` thread has not set its `value` thread variable, and so returns nil when the main thread interrogates it for this variable.  This is how the main thread determines whether `user_input` terminated due to accepting input from the user, or being killed by the `timer` thread.

Comment: +1, but I don't really like this answer, can anyone come up with some more exhaustive answer? Or a link to one, if such answer already exists?

Comment: How can I make this answer more exhaustive?

Comment: By saying what other options besides threads are there, by saing what are up and downsides of using threads, and by showing us how to avoid `sleep` command (busy waiting). I must say that I do not feel I am up to acceptably answering all of this, that's why I am not answering this question myself. But if you take the pain to do it, I am sure that it will make you and your readers alike better programmers.

Comment: @Catnapper, i'd be interested in seeing this code explained if you felt up to editing it.

Comment: @mariozig: I added some explanation of how the threads interact with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Somethink like this?

```
puts "In how many Seconds you want me to beep?"
t = gets.to_i

sleep t
puts "\a WAKE UP!"
```

Comment: No, nope, not `sleep` busy waiting :-)))

Comment: do you want to do other stuff in the same shell you start this script from? Sorry, that's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

My way :

```
comt = 0
while (comt < 10)
    sleep(1)
    comt = comt +1
    puts comt
end#while
```

That display :
1
2
3
...
10