# How to achieve multithreading in ruby on rails ? and what is the way to fetch a thread to kill or wakeup it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

My problem is : I have a jobs table and with each job one thread is initiated. In these threads they do some processing and send a sms and wait for 2 minutes. This is the maximum time. Now if the user responds to the sms then i want to interrupt the corresponding thread to do the rest of the processing.

So is there something by which i can find the thread by name or id from that list ?

Comment: This question is too vague. You achieve multithreading by using multiple threads, and you fetch threads by using Thread.list. But I suspect that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Thread.list gives me whole list of threads. 
My problem is :

I have a jobs table and with each job one thread is initiated.
In these threads they do some processing and send a sms and wait for 2 minutes. This is maximum time.
Now if the user responds to the sms then i want to interrupt the corresponding thead to do the rest of the processing.

Comment: You should consider using a different design; rather than keeping threads around, store the state you need when the job is initiated, then fire off a "complete this task" job when the SMS is responded to. Your existing design will not scale past one instance and is vulnerable to state loss.

Comment: What can be the alternative for threads which can wait for the grace period(2 minutes) too ?

Comment: Why do you want to keep thread to keep waiting for a response?? Can't it be just a simple application flow based on the *state* where a user can proceed only when they respond to SMS and so on?

Comment: Actually if the user responds within 2 minutes then the thread have to be killed and processed further based on the response . if 2 minutes got over and no response came then thread will SMS to sent to next person.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could refer on this answer [Making a timer in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250517/making-a-timer-in-ruby)

```
user_input = Thread.new do
  print "Enter something: "
  Thread.current[:value] = gets.chomp
end

timer = Thread.new { sleep 3; user_input.kill; puts }

user_input.join
if user_input[:value]
  puts "User entered #{user_input[:value]}"
else
  puts "Timer expired"
end
```

if the timer was expired then send it to the next person.